# Structure Nav keeps appending URLs to children

Tags: structure, eeharbor

I am using {exp:structure:nav}, but each child ends up linking to all of its parents' URLs. The selected template, e.g., "stuff/index," is the same for them all. But what happens is below with links in parenthesis:

Page 1 (stuff/page_1) - correct

--Page 1a (stuff/page_1/page_1a)

----Page 1aa (stuff/page_1a/page_1aa)

Any ideas on why this is happening? Or am I doing something wrong?

EE 5.3 / Structure 4.6.1

Comment: can you post your template code for this?

Comment: It is happening from vanilla {exp:structure:nav}. My solution was to use {exp:structure:nav_advanced} with the "Advanced Example" code from http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/navigation_examples, with one difference: I prefixed the href with a slash. (Otherwise, the cascading problem was still happening.) I'm not sure if that indicates some problem with my setup.